# Why is a value not returned if another value is 0 in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a query that does not return the expense value if the drvalue(Debtor Value) is equal to 0 or NULL,
If i change the drvalue to any value greater than 0, query returns the expenses value.

Drvalue is a sum of all the values for a specific period

Below is the query

```
SELECT  f.vehiclenumber,f.fleettype,f.IsCreditor,
ISNULL(SUM(l.DrValue),0) AS drvalue, 
CASE WHEN iscreditor=1 then Sum (DrValue) - Sum(CrValue) else null end AS Profit,
sum(l.CrValue) AS CrValue ,
sum(l.distance) AS LoadDist,
sum(l.DrValue)/DDist AS DRVal ,
d.Liters AS Liters,d.ddist AS DDist, d.DDiesel AS DDiesel, d.DieselCost AS dieslCost, 
(MAX(isnull(l.Closingkm,0))-MIN(isnull(l.OpeningKM,0))) AS [CO],ISNULL(SUM(l.DrValue),0) / CASE WHEN (isnull(MAX(l.Closingkm),0)-MIN(isnull(l.OpeningKM,0)))=0 THEN 1 ELSE (isnull(MAX(l.Closingkm),0)-MIN(isnull(l.OpeningKM,0))) END AS TotalCPK, 
(d.DieselCost/sum(l.DrValue)) * 100 AS DieselPerc, 
SUM(jobdetails.total) AS Expenses, 
count(l.vehicleNo) AS LoadCount 
FROM tblVehicle AS f 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT Vehicleno, loaddate, DrValue, CrValue,Distance, OpeningKM, closingkm FROM tblloads WHERE DrValue IS NOT NULL) AS l ON f.VehicleNumber = l.VehicleNo AND l.loaddate >= '2020-06-01' and l.loaddate <= '2020-06-30' 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT fleet , NULLIF(SUM(Liters),0) AS Liters,NULLIF(sum(distance),0) AS DDist, NULLIF(sum(distance)/ CASE WHEN sum(Liters)=0 THEN 1 ELSE sum(Liters) END,0) AS DDiesel, NULLIF(SUM (Manual_Amount),0) AS DieselCost FROM tblinput 
WHERE [Date] >= '2020-06-01' And [Date] <= '2020-06-30'   
GROUP BY Fleet) AS d ON l.VehicleNo = d.Fleet 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT jd.fleet, SUM(Total) AS total From tblJobDetails jd, tbljobcards WHERE tbljobcards.JobID = jd.jobid AND jobdate >=  '2020-06-01' AND jobdate <=  '2020-06-30'  GROUP BY jd.fleet) AS jobdetails ON jobdetails.fleet = l.vehicleno 
WHERE VehicleCategory <> 'T' 
GROUP BY f.vehiclenumber,f.fleettype,f.IsCreditor,d.Liters,d.ddist, d.DDiesel,d.DieselCost

ORDER BY fleettype
```

[RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xPk7.png)

Comment: (1) Tag with the question you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results would help.  (3) Simplify, simplify, simplify.  Your question is about a couple of columns.   The relationship between your question and the query is not clear.

Comment: Null is always tricky when returning data... If possible try to keep to 0 and it might work better. Especially with joins... Also as Gordon says above. It is quite a big query. Try out the different parts of it and see where you begin to loose results.

Comment: I have attached a pic of the results, I have tried the queries of the joins separately and they return the correct results/values